# Determining assembly containing definition of type for variable in Autos/Locals/Watch window?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Is there any way to, while debugging a .NET assembly, locate the assembly containing the type definition for a variable seen in the Autos, Locals, or Watch windows? For example (and this is just for example purposes, obviously), if I see a variable in the Watch window whose Type column says `System.Type`, is there a way for me to have Visual Studio tell me that `System.Type` is defined in the `mscorlib` assembly?

Edit: I don't need to be able to do this *from* the Watch window (though that would be nice!), just from somewhere within Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that works within those windows, or are you just saying "I can see the variable in some of the windows, but a solution that uses e.g. the Immediate window would be okay"?

Comment: The second one, and I'll update the question to reflect that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever)'s comment led me to a solution: Executing `typeof(<type>)` in the Immediate window will spit out the string representation of the result, which contains everything I need!

For example:

```
typeof(System.Type)
{Name = "Type" FullName = "System.Type"}
    Assembly: {mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}
    AssemblyQualifiedName: "System.Type, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    Attributes: Public | Abstract | Serializable | BeforeFieldInit
    BaseType: {Name = "MemberInfo" FullName = "System.Reflection.MemberInfo"}
    Cache: {System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache}
    ContainsGenericParameters: false
    CustomAttributes: Count = 0x00000005
    DeclaredConstructors: {System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo[0x00000002]}
    DeclaredEvents: {System.Reflection.EventInfo[0x00000000]}
    DeclaredFields: {System.Reflection.FieldInfo[0x00000009]}
    DeclaredMembers: {System.Reflection.MemberInfo[0x0000010e]}
    DeclaredMethods: {System.Reflection.MethodInfo[0x000000c1]}
    DeclaredNestedTypes: {System.Reflection.TypeInfo.<get_DeclaredNestedTypes>d__23}
    DeclaredProperties: {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[0x00000042]}
    DeclaringMethod: '((System.RuntimeType)(typeof(System.Type))).DeclaringMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    DeclaringType: null
    DomainInitialized: false
    ForwardCallBinder: {System.OleAutBinder}
    FullName: "System.Type"
    GUID: {6c9863dc-7207-327f-a048-c3bb63474bfc}
    GenericCache: null
    GenericParameterAttributes: '((System.RuntimeType)(typeof(System.Type))).GenericParameterAttributes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    GenericParameterPosition: '((System.RuntimeType)(typeof(System.Type))).GenericParameterPosition' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    GenericTypeArguments: {System.Type[0x00000000]}
    GenericTypeParameters: {System.Type[0x00000000]}
    HasElementType: false
    HasProxyAttribute: false
    ImplementedInterfaces: {System.Type[0x00000004]}
    InvocationFlags: INVOCATION_FLAGS_INITIALIZED
    IsAbstract: true
    IsAnsiClass: true
    IsArray: false
    IsAutoClass: false
    IsAutoLayout: true
    IsByRef: false
    IsCOMObject: false
    IsClass: true
    IsConstructedGenericType: false
    IsContextful: false
    IsEnum: false
    IsExplicitLayout: false
    IsExportedToWindowsRuntime: false
    IsGenericParameter: false
    IsGenericType: false
    IsGenericTypeDefinition: false
    IsImport: false
    IsInterface: false
    IsLayoutSequential: false
    IsMarshalByRef: false
    IsNested: false
    IsNestedAssembly: false
    IsNestedFamANDAssem: false
    IsNestedFamORAssem: false
    IsNestedFamily: false
    IsNestedPrivate: false
    IsNestedPublic: false
    IsNotPublic: false
    IsPointer: false
    IsPrimitive: false
    IsPublic: true
    IsSealed: false
    IsSecurityCritical: false
    IsSecuritySafeCritical: false
    IsSecurityTransparent: true
    IsSerializable: true
    IsSpecialName: false
    IsSzArray: false
    IsUnicodeClass: false
    IsValueType: false
    IsVisible: true
    IsWindowsRuntimeObject: false
    MemberType: TypeInfo
    MetadataToken: 0x0200013d
    Module (System.Reflection.MemberInfo): {CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary}
    Module: {CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary}
    Name: "Type"
    Namespace: "System"
    NeedsReflectionSecurityCheck: false
    ReflectedType: null
    RemotingCache: {System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.RemotingTypeCachedData}
    StructLayoutAttribute: {System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute}
    TypeHandle: {System.RuntimeTypeHandle}
    TypeInitializer: {Void .cctor()}
    UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "Type" FullName = "System.Type"}
    m_cache: {2956100}
    m_cachedData: {System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.RemotingTypeCachedData}
    m_handle: {1930553888}
    m_invocationFlags: INVOCATION_FLAGS_INITIALIZED
    m_keepalive: null
```

Comment: @ PfhorSlayer, glad to know that you have resolved this issue, thanks for your sharing. If possible, please also mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who meet the same issues. Have a nice day:)